# Is there a practical approach to use transaction URL schema?

Tags: transactions, payments

We are developing a web application, where a user can refill her account by sending funds to the company's Ethereum address. In order to distinguish different users, we assign each user a random unique alpha-numeric token, which should be sent as a data-string with the transaction.

Right now, we are using integration with `MetaMask` through `web3` and it works perfectly.

However, I was wondering, is there a way to make a single-click payment (like with MetaMask), but using Desktop wallets? There is [a discussion about ERC67](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/67), but it looks like a work-in-progress, which is not standardized yet.

Still, is there a practically applicable solution to this problem? We really would like to be able to give the user a link, which she could click and initiate payment in her desktop wallet. Also, it would be nice to embed the link to QR-code and allow payments from mobile devices.

And if such solution does exist, does it support custom `data` field?

Comment: This has been superceded by EIP-681, please see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/681